# How to test an 'action'?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, debugging

I'm working on a registration module. The form has 3 parts, so users fills the first set of information, if everything's correct, he get's the second set and then the third. The first 2 are working fine but I'm facing issues with the 3rd one.

Here I take some information and files that needs to be uploaded. The form is pretty normal itself

```
<form method="post" action="domain.com/marketplace/seller/save">
```

Which remains same for all three forms. The first two works so I know this is right. My action is located in `app/code/community/Manthan/Marketplace/controllers/SellerController.php`. (Manthan is a marketplace extension) Inside, I have my action

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        <?php echo $this->__('save action') ?>
        if($data['formtype'] == 1){
          ...
        }else if($data['formtype'] == 2){
          ...
        }else if($data['formtype'] == 3){
            <?php echo $this->__('formtype 3') ?>
            try {               
                //print_r($_FILES);
                $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email', $data['email'])->getData();                
                $userId = $user['0']['user_id'];                                

                $sellercollection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/seller')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$userId);                              
                $sellerId = $sellercollection->getFirstItem()->getId();

                $seller = Mage::getModel('marketplace/seller')->load($sellerId);                

                $dir_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'marketplace' . DS . 'seller' . DS . 'images' . DS;

                if(isset($_FILES['pan']['name']) && $_FILES['pan']['name'] != '') 
                {
                   try
                   {    
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['pan']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $pan             =  preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-[:space:]]/i', '_', $fileNamewoe) . mt_rand(1000000000, 99999999999);                        
                        $pan        = $pan . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('pan');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        if(!is_dir($dir_path))
                            mkdir($dir_path, 0755, true);

                        $uploader->save($dir_path, $fileNamewithExt);
                        $seller->setPan($pan);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());         
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_FILES['vat_tin_cst']['name']) && $_FILES['vat_tin_cst']['name'] != '') 
                {
                   try
                   {    
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['vat_tin_cst']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $vat_tin_cst       = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-[:space:]]/i', '_', $fileNamewoe) . mt_rand(1000000000, 99999999999);                       
                        $vat_tin_cst= $vat_tin_cst . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('vat_tin_cst');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        if(!is_dir($dir_path))
                            mkdir($dir_path, 0755, true);

                        $uploader->save($dir_path, $fileNamewithExt);
                        $seller->setVatTinCst($vat_tin_cst);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());         
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_FILES['cin']['name']) && $_FILES['cin']['name'] != '') 
                {
                   try
                   {    
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['cin']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $cin       = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-[:space:]]/i', '_', $fileNamewoe) . mt_rand(1000000000, 99999999999);                       
                        $cin= $cin . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('cin');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        if(!is_dir($dir_path))
                            mkdir($dir_path, 0755, true);

                        $uploader->save($dir_path, $fileNamewithExt);
                        $seller->setCin($cin);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());         
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_FILES['cancelled_cheque']['name']) && $_FILES['cancelled_cheque']['name'] != '') 
                {
                   try
                   {    
                        $fileName       = $_FILES['cancelled_cheque']['name'];
                        $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, ".") ,1));
                        $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
                        $cancelled_cheque       = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\\-[:space:]]/i', '_', $fileNamewoe) . mt_rand(1000000000, 99999999999);                      
                        $cancelled_cheque= $cancelled_cheque . '.' . $fileExt;

                        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('cancelled_cheque');
                        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx'));
                        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                        if(!is_dir($dir_path))
                            mkdir($dir_path, 0755, true);

                        $uploader->save($dir_path, $fileNamewithExt);
                        $seller->setCancelledCheque($cancelled_cheque);
                    }
                    catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());         
                    }
                }
                $seller->setBankName($data['panno']);
                $seller->setBankName($data['vat_tin_cstno']);
                $seller->setBankName($data['cinno']);
                $seller->setBankName($data['bank_name']);
                $seller->setBranchName($data['branch_name']);
                $seller->setBeneficiaryName($data['beneficiary_name']);
                $seller->setAccountNumber($data['account_number']);
                $seller->setTypeOfBankAccount($data['type_of_bank_account']);
                $seller->setIfscCode($data['ifsc_code']);
                $seller->save();

                //die('dd');
                //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Thank you for seller registration with us, we will contact you soon.');               
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSellerData(false);           
                $this->_redirect('thank-you-seller');   
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSellerData($data);
                $this->_redirect('register');
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
```

I removed the code for formdata 1 and 2 as they are working fine. I'm concerned with 3, as that is the condition that should be getting triggered this time.

So, what's happening is when I click submit on form 3, the files upload and the form submits but it takes me to a blank page `domain.com/marketplace/seller/save`. There's nothing in the html. I tried putting echo messages in the action but even those don't show up on the page. I've looked into the media folder and the files I selected in the form aren't there.

How do I test what's wrong here?

Comment: I think you have start php tan inside php code, have you check this in you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<?php echo $this->__('save action') ?>` these kind of code from the `saveAction` as you don't need to open a new `<?php` tag inside a method.

Also try something like below to check whether you are receiving the post data:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    print_r($data); die();
    //Other code here....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nidheesh. I didn't realize the php tags were already open. But I put up these tags to find out why the page was not working so that was another issue. The cause of real problem was another syntax error. In formtype 2 code I wrote `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Almost There! We just need some Banking Information to Process your Funds. Then You're all set!');`. The apostrophe in `You're` ended the string and the whole code below it broke. How stupid of me :p